# Скрытие блока

Tags: javascript

Есть форма (поиска) и блок (ответы). Как скрыть блок (с ответами) если я кликну на любое место кроме поля и блока?
Есть код типа

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $(".login");
    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

но он не подходит для этого случая.
Помогите пожалуйста написать код.

Answer (score 1):

При клике на какую либо область, событие клик срабатывает у всех элементов которые находиться на данный момент под курсором. И так как основным элементов у нас является тег html, то вешаем обработчик события на нее